# Browser dies after my websites loads

Tags: localhost

For some reason after I load my website the browser( or the tab it self ) lags , the page become white, All the html elements are deleted( I can see the elements through developers tools in chrome). However, I am unable to close the page 
In safari the whole page become nonfunctional( I can't access any of the developer tools ).

The issue has to do with receiving a ( about 539 characters ) string from a php page through GET ajax.
If I removed the line where the php page prints the string everything works fine.
The ajax request is sent as soon as the page loads.

I am operating through a localhost.

Finally, The error only occurred when I was testing the program. I refreshed the page repeatedly. The problem occur when I refresh the page 3-5 times.
In chrome only, the page lags when I try to open the same page again through another tab. Even if I restarted the computer .

Comment: @user3072635 is that *tap* or **TAB**

Comment: Use $.ajax to make the ajax requests. Use sucess callback

Comment: I think that has to do with the GET string, since it's longer than 255. Use POST instead of GET.

Comment: I think its a tab I might have misspelled it

Comment: @CharlotteDunois GET has a limit on the query length, and it's much more than 255 characters. There's no limit for the response.

Comment: @Juhana The HTTP/1.1 specifications are warning from using more than 255 characters per GET parameter. Also I didn't say anything about response. It's about the request.

Comment: The GET request is way less than 255 its even less than 10. And everything is working fine until the time of the response.

Comment: From the symptoms, I would guess that the server is tying up, not the browser. See if a server restart brings it back to life, without touching the browser.

Comment: It can't be the server because I opened the same page with another browser and it worked just fine